# Centre of gravity of the spherical cap

Tags: physics, spheres

How to calculate centre of gravity of the spherical cap, with known mass, R and h ?

Comment: @Arthur: why do you focus on a hemisphere ? $h$ is given.

Comment: @Arthur: I agree that the mass is superfluous. My question is about *hemi*sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solid sphere, the mass of the section is proportional to $r^2$, i.e. to $R^2-z^2$ (assuming horizontal sections).

Hence the mass

$$\propto\int_{R-h}^R(R^2-z^2)dz=Rh^2-\frac{h^3}3$$ and the moment around an horizontal axis by the sphere center,

$$\propto\int_{R-h}^Rz(R^2-z^2)dz=h^2R^2-Rh^3+\frac{h^4}4.$$

The distance of the gravity center to the sphere center is

$$R\frac{1-\dfrac hR+\dfrac{h^2}{4R^2}}{1-\dfrac h{3R}}.$$

---

For small $h$,

$$R-\frac23h$$ is a good approximation.

[image]

---

If the sphere is hollow, you replace $R^2-z^2$ by $\sqrt{R^2-z^2}$, and WLOG $R=1$,

$$\frac23\frac{\left(2h-h^2\right)^{3/2}}{\dfrac\pi2-\sqrt{2h-h^2}(1-h)-\arcsin(2h-h^2)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the lump was filled.